# Using Flexigrid with an xml formatted source how do you specify how the xml is formatted?

Tags: javascript, xml, flexigrid

I have my columns set as follows:

```
colModel : [
                {display: 'column1', name : 'column1', width : 200, sortable : true, align: 'center'},
                {display: 'column2', name : 'column2', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                {display: 'column3', name : 'column3', width : 100, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                {display: 'column4', name : 'column4', width : 300, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
            ],
```

I set my data source to a url that returns xml. The xml is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items_list>
  <item>
    <column1>BlahBlah</column1>
    <column2>BlahBlah</column2>
    <column3>BlahBlah</column3>
    <column4>BlahBlah</column4>
  </item>

  <item>
    <column1>BlahBlah</column1>
    <column2>BlahBlah</column2>
    <column3>BlahBlah</column3>
    <column4>BlahBlah</column4>
  </item>
</items_list>
```

How can I bind the grid to the xml datasource, it doesn't appear to recognize it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flexigrid expects xml to be formatted in a specific way like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rows>
    <page>1</page>
    <total>2</total>
    <row id='1'>
        <cell><![CDATA[abc]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[abc]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[abc]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[123]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[123]]></cell>
    </row>
    <row id='2'>
        <cell><![CDATA[abc]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[abc]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[abc]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[123]]></cell>
        <cell><![CDATA[123]]></cell>
    </row>
  </rows>
```

Comment: Awesome mmcgrail. Do you happen to have any additional examples? (links etc?) The CDATA identifier is always the same, it doesn't have to match up with column names?

Comment: I don't have any examples because I use json. the <![CDATA[blahblah]]> is your values. so each cell should be inline with the way you have the columns setup in the flexigrid, follow ?

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work.. Does the "cell" entry have to match up with column name instead of the word cell? Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: can you update your post with the new xml that your using please

Answer (score -1):

it doesn't work because flexigrid won't accept formatted xml

you will need to strip out tabs and en of line characters.